# Use izip to read lines from two files simultaneously in python

Tags: python, line

I'm trying to use 'izip' to read lines simultaneously from two files, however got errors like below:

```
>>> f1=open('/home/xug/scratch/test/test_1.fastq','r')
>>> f2=open('/home/xug/scratch/test/test_2.fastq','r')
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> for i,line1,line2 in izip(f1,f2):
...     if i%4==3:
...        print line1,line2
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

I don't know why....what is "need more than 2 values"?
thx

Comment: You may need to use `itertools.izip_longest(f1, f2)` if you need to iterate all lines and the files are not of equal length

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`izip()` simply zips the two iterables to pairs.  It doesn't introduce an additional counter, as you seem to expect.  Try using `enumerate()`

```
for i, (line1, line2) in enumerate(izip(f1, f2)):
    ...
```

to also get that counter.

The error message results from the attempt to assign the first item of your iterable to `i, line1, line2`.  Since the first item is a pair of strings, say `s1` and `s2`, this assignment would be essentially equivalent to

```
i, line1, line2 = s1, s2
```

which would clearly needs more than two values to unpack.  (To be precise, it would need three.)